# DNA to RNA Transcription

Tags: code-golf, string

## Guidelines

#### Task

Given a DNA strand, return its RNA complement (per RNA transcription).

Both DNA and RNA strands are a sequence of nucleotides.

The four nucleotides found in DNA are adenine (**A**), cytosine (**C**),
guanine (**G**) and thymine (**T**).

The four nucleotides found in RNA are adenine (**A**), cytosine (**C**),
guanine (**G**) and uracil (**U**).

Given a DNA strand, its transcribed RNA strand is formed by replacing
each nucleotide with its complement:

- `G` -> `C`
- `C` -> `G`
- `T` -> `A`
- `A` -> `U`

---

#### Rules

- The input will always be either a string or an array/list of characters
- The output should always be either a string or an array/list of characters
- In the case of invalid input, you should output `'Invalid Input'` as a string or an array/list of characters
- You can assume that you will only be given printable ASCII characters.
- This is code golf so the person with the least amount of bytes winsx

---

#### Examples

`'C' -> 'G'`

`'A' -> 'U'`

`'ACGTGGTCTTAA' -> 'UGCACCAGAAUU'`

`'XXX' -> 'Invalid Input'`

`'ACGTXXXCTTAA' -> 'Invalid Input'`

---

#### Other info

This task was taken from [Exercism](https://exercism.io), which was founded by Katrina Owen and is licensed under the MIT License.

Comment: Can we assume that the input will contain only printable ASCII characters? If not, what range of characters can appear in the input?

Comment: Boo-urns to input validation!

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes only printable ASCII characters, however you must still check that it is valid input.

Comment: I assume `U` is illegal input? At least one answer currently fails if that's true.

Comment: [Here is a meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8858/58563) explaining why input validation is usually discouraged. In this particular case, it also prevents the use of arithmetic solutions.

Comment: I remember seeing a sandboxed challenge like this that says "deleted too simple and probably dupe of many other things" something like that.

Comment: (Recommend sandbox)

Comment: Side note: `https://exercism.io/` does not work for me. It's working fine without SSL, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 23 bytes

```
„—ÄGu©ÃQi®"GUAC"‡ë”Í¼î®
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf8wNWFiMWX//@KAnuKAlMOER3XCqcODUWnCriJHVUFDIuKAocOr4oCdw43CvMOuwq7//0FDR1RHR1RDVFRBQQ)

**Explanation**

```
„—ÄGu©                    # push "CATG" and store a copy in register
      Ã                   # keep only those letters of input
       Qi                 # if the result equals the input
         ®"GUAC"‡         # translate "CATG" to "GUAC"
                 ë”Í¼î®   # else, push "Invalid Input"
```

Comment: Moar guacamole pls

Answer (score 1):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>36</s> 31 bytes

```
T`GCTAp`CGAUx
K'x`Invalid input
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8D8kwd05xLEgwdndMbSCy1u9IsEzrywxJzNFITOvoLTk/39nLkcuR2f3EHf3EOeQEEdHroiICLAAkAYLAAA)

#### Explanation

```
T`GCTAp`CGAUx
```

Perform the required character substitutions as a transliteration, while also replacing all invalid characters with `x`.

```
K'x`Invalid input
```

If the result contains `x` (i.e. the input contained an invalid character), replace it with the constant string `Invalid input`.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok) / [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 38 bytes

**Solution:**

```
(x;"Invalid Input")@|/^x:"CGAU""GCTA"?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X6PCWskzrywxJzNFwTOvoLRESdOhRj@uwkrJ2d0xVEnJ3TnEUcleydHZPcTdPcQ5JMTRUen/fwA)

**Examples:**

```
q)k)(x;"Invalid Input")@|/^x:"CGAU""GCTA"?"C"
"G"
q)k)(x;"Invalid Input")@|/^x:"CGAU""GCTA"?"C"
"G"
q)k)(x;"Invalid Input")@|/^x:"CGAU""GCTA"?"G"
"C"
q)k)(x;"Invalid Input")@|/^x:"CGAU""GCTA"?"ACGTGGTCTTAA"
"UGCACCAGAAUU"
q)k)(x;"Invalid Input")@|/^x:"CGAU""GCTA"?"XXX"
"Invalid Input"
q)k)(x;"Invalid Input")@|/^x:"CGAU""GCTA"?"ACGTXXXCTTAA"
"Invalid Input"
```

**Explanation:**

The mapping is trivial. 25 bytes for the "Invalid Input" portion.

```
(x;"Invalid Input")@|/^x:"CGAU""GCTA"? / the solution
                               "GCTA"? / return index in left list
                         "CGAU"        / index into this list
                       x:              / save as x
                      ^                / null, any nulls in x?
                    |/                 / take max
                   @                   / index into
( ;               )                    / two item list
   "Invalid Input"                     / result if null found
 x                                     / result if no nulls found
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>103</s> <s>95</s> 86 bytes

```
def f(b):
 try:return["CGAU"["GCTA".index(i)]for i in b]
 except:return"Invalid Input"
```

Or, if lowercase inputs count:

```
def f(b):
 try:return["cgau"["gcta".index(i.lower())]for i in b]
 except:return"Invalid Input"
```

Comment: Why not uuse "GCTA" and "CGAU" and remove the .lower()?

Comment: further to the above I think `"acgt"` should be considered invalid input.

Comment: @streetster I wasn't sure whether or not the lowercase letters counted as valid inputs.

Comment: Can't you inline `a` and `c` like `try:return["CGAU"["GCTA".index(i)]for i in b]`?

Comment: @Laikoni I didn't think of that, changed!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>82</s> <s>79</s> 67 bytes

thanks to Laikoni for -3 bytes!
-12 bytes by looking at this 3 years later.

```python
lambda s:{*s}-{*'ACGT'}and'Invalid Input'or s.translate('UCG A'*17)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqlqruFa3Wkvd0dk9RL02MS9F3TOvLDEnM0XBM6@gtEQ9v0ihWK@kKDGvOCexJFVDPdTZXcFRXcvQXPN/GkhOITNPQd1ZXUdB3RFMAI1xdw9xDglxBPMjIiJgwkAmRNiKS0GhoCgzr0QjTaNYU/M/sh4A)

[`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) takes any kind of collection of characters or codepoints that can be indexed into with an integer, in this case we use a string.

| `c` | `ord(c)` | `ord(c)%5` | `('UCG A'*20)[ord(c)]` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `'A'` | `65` | `0` | `'U'` |
| `'C'` | `67` | `2` | `'G'` |
| `'G'` | `71` | `1` | `'C'` |
| `'T'` | `84` | `4` | `'A'` |

Comment: 79 bytes with `"".join("UCG A"[ord(c)%5]for c in s)`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqlqruFa3Wkvd0dk9RL02MS9F3TOvLDEnM0XBM6@gtEQ9v0hJSS8rPzNPQynU2V3BUSk6vyhFI1lT1TQ2Lb9IIVkhM0@hWPM/iF0MYqs7q@soqDuCCaCR7u4hziEhjmB@REQETBjIhAhbcSkoFBRl5pVopGkUa2r@R9YDAA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org),<strike>118</strike> 114 bytes

```
func[s][t: copy{}foreach c s[append t switch/default to-word c[G[{C}]C[{G}]T[{A}]A[{U}]][return"Invalid Input"]]t]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcq9CsIwFEDh3ae4ZBd3t5AhdJUIhcsdSn5ooSQhvbFIyLNXwUFxO3yc4t1x8w6QIFyPUKPFjZCvYFN@th5S8ZOdwcKGU84@OmDY9oXtfHE@THVl4HTeU3FgUWNTnRQ23clgk50ktnsnwuK5liiG@JjWxcEQc2VBxHTkskSGAEKK07eVNlobZYz85XEc/6a3fKbjBQ)

Ungolfed:

```
f: func [s] [ 
    t: copy {}                              ; initialize t to an empty string
    foreach c s [                           ; for each character c of the input
        append t switch/default to-word c [ ; append to t the following if c is one of GCTA
            G [{C}]
            C [{G}]
            T [{A}]
            A [{U}] 
        ]
        [ return "Invalid Input" ]          ; otherwise return "Invalid Input"
    ]     
    t                                       ; return t
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## GNU sed, <s>70</s> 43 bytes

```
s/^.*[^ATCG].*$/Invalid Input/
y/ATCG/UAGC/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1g/Tk8rOs4xxNk9Vk9LRd8zrywxJzNFwTOvoLREn6tSHySjH@ro7qz//78jl6Oze4i7e4hzSIijI1dERARYAEiDBQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/) or MinGW, 110 bytes

```c
f(s){for(char*t="GCTA",*o=s=strdup(s),*q;*o;o++)(q=strchr(t,*o))?*o="CGAU"[q-t]:(s="Invalid input!");puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwDIbP9ilqQGi7@QKWKqOH4r3CQDyMyeZA263tvMiefWYehqck//eRpN7Xz8q189ywyD@ND6x@VEEkBUbbAnLhVVQxhfvYo5CLQQovfZZxNixx/QgsocT5CU3QprjAddin24FFBWf3rp7dnXauH9MWuMQScY2c5rfHvP0doyJy8iGbPnQuNQx2kaojhZyiSDbLX5JMhCCkr6pz7Ce3DDQsHJtibbSxxlhtbbFmZVn@YxxXPM1f)

Answer (score 1):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), <s>75</s> 70 bytes

```
s->set(s)-set('ACGT')and'Invalid Input'or["UCG A"[ord(c)%5]for c in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUw9C8MgFNz7Kx6B8hTi2KVQQRwku4VA2yGYBoRUJc9kyn9PTUqX@@LuXHQxzHkbbs@NhKR3ZsTFTqi0sci70GMTlm70PTQhzRnjBJ8uMSdkddcGVPWIU88cP19eNfFVjp7KX2kR@ACosQZUB5RDY6y2Vh2@bdt/XOQvvp4AynCVMOyQJh/y9gU) A mix of [ovs' Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156059/56433) and my [Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156067/56433).

*Edit: -5 bytes thanks to ovs!*

Comment: [This is shorter with a list comprehension](https://tio.run/##NYwxC8MgFIT3/opHoLwEkrFLoQFxkOwWhDRD0ApCeQY1nfrfraZ0ufvu4E577WlP2d4eOQ5jfKY2dkM1ZFxI7FYyONF7fTkDE217Qh/m5s4FsGb2wbS6O18W6wNocARxyZVjZeTYA7JDypcQkkvJjqyU@tcFf/X1BFCGnxFslS04SvkL). But I think returning a `map` object would be valid as well and is another byte shorter.

Comment: @ovs Thanks! Is there any consensus on map objects?

Comment: There is no specific consensus regarding iterators, but it is [allowed to write a generator function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/64121). This is quite similar as the return value of a generator function is an generator, which is a specific type of an iterator just like a map object.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](http://cjam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), 43 bytes

```
l{"GCTA"#"CGAU "=}%_S#){];"Invalid input"}&
```

Online interpreter: http://cjam.aditsu.net/

Answer (score 0):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) with `-p`, 39 bytes

```perl
y/GCTA/CGAU/<y///c?$_="Invalid Input":0
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to [wastl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78123/wastl)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79S3905xFHf2d0xVN@mUl9fP9leJd5WyTOvLDEnM0XBM6@gtETJyuD/f2cuRy5HZ/cQd/cQ55AQR0euiIgIsACQBgv8yy8oyczPK/6vW5ADAA)

Comment: Two other 41 bytes solutions (both `-p`): [`s/.*[^GCTA].*/Invalid Input/;y;GCTA;CGAU`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX08rOs7dOcQxVk9L3zOvLDEnM0XBM6@gtETfutIaJGHt7O4Y@v@/o7N7iLt7iHNIiKPjv/yCksz8vOL/ugUA) and [`y/GCTA/CGAU/<length?$_='Invalid Input':0`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79S3905xFHf2d0xVN8mJzUvvSTDXiXeVt0zrywxJzNFwTOvoLRE3crg/39HZ/cQd/cQ55AQR8d/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Comment: @wastl Oh, nice. Using `y///c` instead of `length` your second saves a byte! Thank you!

Comment: We don't count flags as bytes anymore; instead, we count flags as separate languages altogether, so this answer is "Perl 5 + `-p`, 39 bytes" and not "Perl 5, 39 bytes + 1 (`-p`) = 40".

Comment: Thanks @EriktheOutgolfer I keep forgetting this. Old habits and all that...

Comment: Well, it's my question over meta which has the consensus, no wonder I've been immediately used to it. :P

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 192 bytes

```
@echo off
set/ps=
set t=%s:A=%
set t=%t:C=%
set t=%t:G=%
set t=%t:T=%
if not "%t%"=="" echo Invalid Input&exit/b
set s=%s:A=U%
set s=%s:C=A%
set s=%s:G=C%
set s=%s:A=G%
echo %s:T=A%
```

Takes input on STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 78 bytes

```js
f=([c,...r],s='',k='GCTA'.indexOf(c))=>c?~k?f(r,s+'CGAU'[k]):'Invalid input':s
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=([c,...r],s='',k='GCTA'.indexOf(c))=>c?~k?f(r,s+'CGAU'[k]):'Invalid input':s

console.log(f('C'           )) // 'G'
console.log(f('A'           )) // 'U'
console.log(f('ACGTGGTCTTAA')) // 'UGCACCAGAAUU'
console.log(f('XXX'         )) // 'Invalid Input'
console.log(f('ACGTXXXCTTAA')) // 'Invalid Input'
```

---

#### Without input validation (non-competing)

47 bytes using `search()`:

```js
f=([c,...r])=>c?'CGAU'['GCTA'.search(c)]+f(r):r
```

48 bytes using a hash:

```js
f=([c,...r])=>c?'UCG_A'[parseInt(c,36)%5]+f(r):r
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 75 bytes

```hs
f s|all(`elem`"GCTA")s=["UCG A"!!mod(fromEnum c)5|c<-s]
f _="Invalid Input"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NCsJADITvfYqYy7ZgvXmzQgiyCHpyC4UidukPirurWPWiPnttrYKClzD5mMlkq@t9aUzTVFDftTF@VprSZihZEQZ1lGLMEggHA3so/Op0sDN3sZAH43s@Ceu1V8Emwrm7arMrYO6OlzM2Vu8cRGD1cQl@S1bn08LBCKogRcYhIL0GSyWlYqXotSdJ8sGt7PHau4WeYAHhFIQUnqBexp38yr@pZGImSRR3hvZKz3/eeyc/FX8d4aN5Ag) The mapping is done by taking the character values mod 5 and indexing into the string `"UCG A"`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>24</s>  23 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“ɠ{>dʠ»ɓ,Ṛ;⁾TUyðḟ?“TGCA
```

A full program printing the result (a monadic link is  <s>25</s>  24 with a closing `”` appended)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9qZWxsef//4oCcyaB7PmTKoMK7yZMs4bmaO@KBvlRVecOw4bifP@KAnFRHQ0H///8iQUNHVENUVEFBIg)**

#### How?

```
“ɠ{>dʠ»ɓ,Ṛ;⁾TUyðḟ?“TGCA - Main Link: list of characters
                  “TGCA - literal list of characters = ['T','G','C','A']
                 ?      - if...
                ḟ       - ...condition: filter discard (empty is falsey)
“ɠ{>dʠ»                 - ...then: compressed string = "Invalid Input"
       ɓ       ð        - ...else: dyadic chain with swapped arguments:
         Ṛ              - reverse = ['A','C','G','T']
        ,               - pair = [['T','G','C','A'],['A','C','G','T']]
           ⁾TU          - literal list of characters = ['T','U']
          ;             - concatenate = [['T','G','C','A'],['A','C','G','T'],'T','U']
              y         -   translate...
                        -   ... 1: {'T'->'A';'G'->'C';'C'->'G';'A'->'T'}
                        -   ... 2: {'T'->'U'}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 128 bytes

```c
k,l;f(S){char*s=S,b[l=strlen(s)],*t=b;for(;*t++=(k=*s++)-65?k-67?k-71?k-84?0:65:67:71:85;);puts(strlen(b)-l?"Invalid Input":b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxCoMwAER3v0KcEjVQoUZJCCIO4mwGoXQwtrZimhaTdhG/3WZoi/SG43h3XIcuXbeuYyhpD2o4d9d28jWrQ3GQTJtJnhXQ8Bj6hgna3ydAfRMEDIzM10EAEY6zEeHEWhJZS/fZjuCY4IQkEUljCunjaTT4PAmIZOZV6tXK4eRWynYeEZAu66CMe2sHBaAzO65VD7zCg/Sb820uSl6WvOA83@Kmaf5GlvxGy/oG)

**Unrolled:**

```c
k, l;
f(S)
{
    char *s=S, b[l=strlen(s)], *t=b;
    for(; *t++ = (k=*s++)-65 ? k-67 ? k-71 ? k-84 ? 0 : 65 : 67 : 71 : 85;);
    puts(strlen(b)-l ? "Invalid Input" : b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 66 bytes

Prompts for screen input of original string

```
('CGAU',⊂'Invalid Input')[(((⍴n)×~m)↑n),(m←0<+/(n←,'GTCA'⍳⎕)=5)↑5]
```

Comment: How many bytes?

Comment: @Laurel Thanks for spotting my omission. Corrected.

Comment: @Laikoni That is strange I edited it, checked it and the count was there. Just gone back and it was gone. I have re-edited and checked and it is there now

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 75 bytes

```r
function(s)"if"(grepl("[^ACGT]",s),"Invalid Input",chartr("ACGT","UGCA",s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcq9CoAgFAbQvaeIb7oX7A1aoiHaa4oCsSwhLMzCt7e/7QzHRZ3mWdSnVd5slg6G0aDZTftK6IairJoe4mCB2l5yNWNa2/30EGqRzjvCOyDQVmXxPo6aEEIAJw@kmv2vr3G8AQ)